# Pass SIGINT through bash script to application

Tags: linux, bash, sigint

I have a Linux application, written in C++, which traps the SIGINT interrupt in order to do some final cleanup before exiting. I call this application within a bash script. Now, when I type control-C with the bash script running in the foreground, the script terminates as does the program it invoked but without running the final cleanup code. How can I have the interrupt pass through the bash script, directly to the application, resulting in the final cleanup and then a normal exit which then causes the script itself to exit?

Answer (score 1):

`bash` also has the ability to [trap SIGINT](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_12_02.html). It would be feasible to trap the signal so the script doesn't die, and then in the trap handler, use `kill` to pass the signal off to your application.

Answer (score 1):

```
#somecommand has to be a unique substring of the command being run

trap "kill -3 %?somecommand" sigint

somecommand&
wait %?somecommand
```